# Inno Setup second temporary directory

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup creates a temporary directory for the installer, which is assigned to the `{tmp}` constant. However, it also creates a second temporary directory in the same format (e.g. is-KIQQJ.tmp) as the main temporary directory. It appears that this is used by the uninstaller, as Setup.tmp is created in here. Can the value of this second temporary directory be returned in the `[Code]` section?

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: Sometimes if the installer terminated, it leaves this temporary folder behind. If I can log these to a file (including the `{tmp}` constant), I can check for both and remove any orphaned folders created by previously terminated installer processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a temporary directory of the main/parent installer process. The `setup.tmp` (or `mysetup.tmp`) is the child installer - the actual installation process.

As such, you can retrieve the path to the `*setup.tmp` using a [`ParamStr(0)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_paramstr) call (= path to running binary). And extract its folder using the [`ExtractFilePath` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extractfilepath).

```pascal
ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))
```